# mssql PERCENTILE_CONT group by year

Tags: sql-server, query, group-by

I am trying to prepare a dataset for box chart which requires MAX, MIN, MEDIAN and quartiles grouped by years. This is my attempt, however I could not group it by years:

```
SELECT
    years,
    MAX(NET_MERIT) AS high_end,
    max(q3) as q3,
    max(MEDIAN) as median,
    max(q1) as q1,
    min(NET_MERIT) as low_end

    from(

    select Year(FA_BDATE) as years ,NET_MERIT,
    PERCENTILE_CONT(0.25) within group(order by NET_MERIT) over (partition by Year(FA_BDATE)) as q1,
    PERCENTILE_CONT(0.50) within group(order by NET_MERIT) over (partition by Year(FA_BDATE)) as MEDIAN,
    PERCENTILE_CONT(0.75) within group(order by NET_MERIT) over (partition by Year(FA_BDATE)) as q3
    from HerdAnalytics_tbl
    group by Year(FA_BDATE)
    order by Year(FA_BDATE)

    

    ) as sub
    order by years
```

The table is like this: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=502462f6ac6a30effc65bc28e5ff4c1a)

| FA_BDATE | NET_MERIT |
| --- | --- |
| 01-01-2009 | 175.23 |
| 01-01-2008 | 185.23 |
| 01-01-2009 | 195.23 |
| 01-01-2010 | 165.23 |

And I have a small question: is `PERCENTILE_CONT(0.50)` is the median itself?

Comment: Now that I read your question more carefully, I see your main question is not the `PERCENTILE_CONT`, but the use of group by year. Please, provide the DDL for the table and some sample data so that your problem can be reproduced.

Comment: @Ronaldo thank you for your time .. i edited the question as you told

Comment: Please, check the edited answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, using `PERCENTILE_CONT(0.50)` is a way of finding the median. You can check the [Basic syntax example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/percentile-cont-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#a-basic-syntax-example) section of the `PERCENTILE_CONT` doc to see an example.

About the `GROUP BY`, the `PARTITION BY` clause is already creating groups of years, so you don't need to use a group by on the subquery. Also, you shouldn't use `ORDER BY` on that subquery, or you'll get the error:

> The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived
> tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET
> or FOR XML is also specified.

Try your query like this:

```
SELECT
    years,
    MAX(NET_MERIT) AS high_end,
    MAX(q3) AS q3,
    MAX(MEDIAN) AS median,
    MAX(q1) AS q1,
    MIN(NET_MERIT) AS low_end

FROM(

    SELECT YEAR(FA_BDATE) AS years ,NET_MERIT,
    PERCENTILE_CONT(0.25) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY NET_MERIT) OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(FA_BDATE)) AS q1,
    PERCENTILE_CONT(0.50) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY NET_MERIT) OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(FA_BDATE)) AS MEDIAN,
    PERCENTILE_CONT(0.75) WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY NET_MERIT) OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(FA_BDATE)) AS q3
    FROM HerdAnalytics_tbl    

) AS sub
GROUP BY years
ORDER BY years;
```